# Excel: Macro for dragging formula down to end of column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using a macro that creates a copy of a worksheet then renames it, deletes some columns and inserts a formula into a cell and then drags it down.

The part that drags it down does not work!

```
Sub filterData()
'
' filterData Macro
' Filter data
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+m
'
    Sheets("devices").Select
    Sheets("devices").Copy After:=Sheets(1)
    Sheets("devices (2)").Select
    Sheets("devices (2)").Name = "filterData"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Columns("G:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:AA").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=LEFT(devices!RC[4],IFERROR(SEARCH("""""""",devices!RC[4]),SEARCH(""-"",devices!RC[4]))-1)"
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("G2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Table122[Display]")
    Range("Table122[Display]").Select
    End Sub
```

[image]

As you can see, the part that drags the formula down to last populated cell is not working!!!

**Update**

I have added the following to the code as well and it still does not work;

```
lastrow = Range("G2").End(xlUp).Row --new line
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=LEFT(devices!RC[4],IFERROR(SEARCH("""""""",devices!RC[4]),SEARCH(""-"",devices!RC[4]))-1)"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G" & lastrow) --new line
```

Comment: is the table "Table122"?

Comment: that was added by the macro automatically, i removed it and tried defining the range manually but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a Table (VBA ListObject) you can fill in the whole ListColumn at once:

```
ActiveCell.ListObject.ListColumns("Display").DataBodyRange.Formula = _ 
    "=LEFT(devices!RC[4],IFERROR(SEARCH("""""""",devices!RC[4]),SEARCH(""-"",devices!RC[4]))-1)"
```

Also, note that you can get rid of the `Select` statements generated by the Macro Recorder. For example:

```
Columns("G:J").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

can be just:

```
Columns("G:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

And one final tip is to fully qualify ranges, e.g.:

```
Worksheets("filterData").Columns("G:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

I'll stop now since you already accepted this answer. Except to say I do like the animation!

Comment: Thanks! I try to give as much detail as possible!

Comment: Awesome, I use liceCap!, I managed to shrink the code down to 5 lines with your suggestions. is it possible to merge the following `    Columns("G:J").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("H:AA").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` into one, something like     `Columns("G:J,H:AA").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Comment: I just used one on [my blog](http://yoursumbuddy.com/escape-accidental-file-moves/) last night. (Shameless promotion)

Comment: Sure, try something like:`ActiveSheet.Range("G:J,M:AA").EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your macro is probably this line:

```
Range("Table122[Display]").Select
```

You are trying to auto-fill the Display column, including the Header row, which it probably doesn't like.  Try it like this instead:

```
Range("Table122[[#Data],[Display]]").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution to macro for dragging formula down to dynamic row count:

You can also use the previous column for a reference of how many rows you want to drag the formula.

**Generic: Range("B2:B" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "{=formulahere}"**

So in your case it would look something like:

Range("G2:G" & Range("F65000").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(devices!RC[4],IFERROR(SEARCH("""""""",devices!RC[4]),SEARCH(""-"",devices!RC[4]))-1)"